# How to convert json of fields with values in Arrays into typed List of custom class?

Tags: java, json, jackson-databind

I am trying to deserialize json into my class using `java`'s `jackson-databind`. The json is formated like this:

> sample.json

```
    { 
    ...,
    "random" : { 
        "field1" : ["x1","y1","z1","a1","b1"],
        "field2" : ["x2","y2","z2","a2","b2"],
        "field3" : ["x3","y3","z3","a3","b3"]
        }
    }
```

I want to read this json to `List<MyClass> myList` of size 5 `[xMy,yMy,zMy,aMy,bMy]`. `MyClass` has attributes: `String field1`, `String field2`, `String field3`. xMy element should have list of [x1,x2,x3]. yMy should have list of [y1,y2,y3]. zMy should have list of [z1,z2,z3].

```
    public class MyClass {
        private String field1;
        private String field2;
        private String field3;
        
        ...
    }
```

So the result variable will be `List<MyClass> myList`.

> UltraSmartLogic.java code

```
JsonNode node = new ObjectMapper().readTree(json);
JsonNode randomNode = node.get("random");
ObjectReader reader = new ObjectMapper().readerFor(new TypeReference<List<String>>() {});
List<String> field1ValueList = reader.readValue(randomNode.get("field1"));
List<MyClass> myList = ???
```

This is just simplified json, real json contains 7 fields and 1000 values for each field.
Goal here is to create 1000 instances of `MyClass` inside `myList`. First element should be mapped with x1,x2,x3, second element should be mapped with y1,y2,y3, third - z1,z2,z3 and so on thousand times...

`field1ValueList` is no use, because this way I will have 7 `List` variables and 7 `for` loops iterating 1000 times each plus one more loop to set values into `List<MyClass> myList`. I believe jackson is more effective and able to deserialize this, I just don't know how. Yet.

Comment: something like this would be perfect: `new ObjectMapper().readerFor(new TypeReference<List<MyClass>>() {}).readValue(randomNode)`

Comment: If each `MyClass` should contain 3 elements, why does it have 3 lists?

Comment: good point, I have updated the post now. still does not work

Comment: Jackson is not designed to restructure data. I would suggest deserializing with the original layout and then transforming the result in ordinary Java.